# Why do i need put -1 instead of 0 to get correct code?

Tags: javascript, counting

```
    let str = "Hello world";
    let target = "o";
    let pos = -1;
    while ((pos = str.indexOf(target, pos + 1)) != -1) {
      console.log( pos );
    }
```

When pos is - 1 it works fine, but when I set 0 and remove + 1 it returns endless 4. Why does it happen?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: `pos + 1`; what happens here if you use 0 vs -1?

Comment: string.indexOf(searchvalue, start),   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp  .  Will work depending on the size of target and the start parameter.

Comment: @mykaf basically it'll stop working if target is H...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not increase the position, it repeats 4 indefinitely because you are always doing the exact same check. Removing variables and using just this part:

```
pos = str.indexOf(target, pos)
```

This would mean:

```
str.indexOf(target, 0) // Returns 4
str.indexOf(target, 4) // Returns 4
str.indexOf(target, 4) // etc
```

That's because indexOf will start looking at the exact index that it just found so it will find the o again. Adding +1 makes sure that it continues looking PAST last occurence found.